# Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

Tags: callback, dart, dart-js-interop

I'm using the (2.0)js-interop library in combination with the JS library [ImageLoaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) and I'm stuck the `FunctionProxy` class because the code below throw the following error:

> Breaking on exception: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

```dart
js.FunctionProxy loaded = new js.FunctionProxy((){
      print("called");
      js.Proxy pckry = new js.Proxy(context.Packery, container, options);
    });
    
js.Proxy img = new js.Proxy(context.imagesLoaded, container, loaded);
```

Which is weird because my js callback is called 5 times before the app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the *Usage* section of [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) it looks like the callback takes one parameter. So you have to add this parameter to your callback :

```dart
js.FunctionProxy loaded = new js.FunctionProxy((instance) {
  print("called");
  js.Proxy pckry = new js.Proxy(context.Packery, container, options);
});

js.Proxy img = new js.Proxy(context.imagesLoaded, container, loaded);
```

Additional notes :

- You can avoid `new js.FunctionProxy`. There are only a limited number of cases where it's needed and your case here is not one of them.
- `imagesLoaded` can be use as a function and it simplifies the code.

Thus, you should be able to use :

```dart
final img = context.imagesLoaded(container, (instance) {
  print("called");
  js.Proxy pckry = new js.Proxy(context.Packery, container, options);
});
```