# Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call' again

Tags: callback, dart, dart-js-interop

Exactly one month ago I encountered this problem [Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20049766/2084450) with js interop.

Now I have the same problem with the [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/) library. I'm using it in combination with JsInterop since a moment. Today i tried to use the [mouseover](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.mouseover) function and I get the same exception.

But when I hover the SVG element my function is fired four times :

```
hover in
hover in
hover in
hover in 
Breaking on exception: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'
```

I tried :

```dart
var img = s.image("$url", x, y, image.width/2, image.height/2); 
js.FunctionProxy hover = new js.FunctionProxy(() {
  print("hover in");
});

img.mouseover(hover);
```

and

```dart
var img = s.image("$url", x, y, image.width/2, image.height/2);
img.mouseover(() {
  print("hover in");
});
```

This time I checked twice and there is no extra arguments for the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the logs you paste, the *mouseover* handler seems to be called sometimes with parameters sometimes without. To handle that you can use a function with optional parameters :

```dart
var img = s.image("$url", x, y, image.width/2, image.height/2);
img.mouseover(([p1, p2, p3, p4]) {
  print("hover in");
});
```

The above callback now handles calls with from 0 to 4 parameters.

Comment: Damn... it did the trick... It's very weird... Thanks you agin Alexandre !